# Cámara no detectada raspberry

Tags: cámara, raspberry

Seré breve, estoy trabajando con cámaras en Raspberry. Y por razones que desconozco la Raspberry no detecta la cámara que le tengo conectada. Al ejecutar desde terminal vcgencmd get_camera me devuelve la siguiente respuesta "supported=1 detected=0 libcamera Interfaces=1". He consultado diferentes fuentes y documentación, pero nada de lo que he probado me ha servido. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Raspberry? ¿Qué modelo y tipo de cámara? ¿Qué interfaz de conexión? Faltan muchos detalles en tu pregunta. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y agrega toda la información relevante. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Dices que *serás breve*, pero creo que se necesita justo lo contrario.